# How to remove "OTHER ACTIONS" from the signing experience

Tags: docusignapi

I am using a Custom Signing Resource file . Can you please tell me the name of the property to disable the Other Options.
I know that Other Options will rename the Other Options. I want to set the Other Options to false in resource file .Which attribute do I set false to for removing the other actions drop down altogether.

Ideally I want to completely remove the OTHER ACTIONS box.  Any help would be appreciated.
 [image for the other actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geyGY.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to completely remove/brand out the Other Actions box. The only options you have is to limit the options that are displayed via branding or account settings.